# trouble with add/remove class on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list and each LI element have a button.
Also when click(tap) the button, adding the class "on".

So this is my code here

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="btn">txt 1</li>
<li><a href="#" class="btn">txt 2</li>
<li><a href="#" class="btn">txt 3</li>
</ul>

<style>
.btn { background:blue }
.btn.on { background:red }
</style>

<script>
 $(document).on('vmousedown','.btn' ,function(){
        $(".btn").addClass('on');
    }).on('vmouseup', function(){
        $(".btn").removeClass('on');
    }).on("vmousecancel", function() {
        $(".btn").removeClass('on');
     });
</script>
```

The problem is when I press button on `Txt1`, All buttons adding class "on".

I want to add a class only the one that i clicked.

How do i fix this script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an event is fired, the `this` keyword refers to the element that fired the event. So, to access the specific button you pressed:

```
$(document).on('vmousedown','.btnPhone' ,function(){
        $(this).addClass('on');
    }).on('vmouseup', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('on');
}).on("vmousecancel", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('on');
 });
```

Comment: oh I have another question, If I have another class of buttons, Do I need to duplicated the whole code and just change the class name?

Comment: @user3400080 - At stackoverflow, each question must be self-contained. If you have another question, just start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').click(function(e){
    $(e.delegateTarget).addClass('on');
});
```